# Vim colorscheme general attributes?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

I'm making a colorscheme for Vim and have a command that allows me to view the 'scope' of a attribute to highlight, but I need some of the general attributes (background, line numbers, etc.) so I can properly create my scheme. Is there any good cheat sheets or lists of some of the attributes? I checked all the Vim documentation and wikis but they don't list many things that affect the editor itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is such a list. All you need is in Vim's *awesomely-exhaustive-but-sometimes-cryptic* documentation: `:help syntax`, more specifically `:help highlight-default` for a list of default highlight groups. If something is not there it probably means that it can't be done or that it's custom/syntax-dependant.

You could also open a pre-existing [colorscheme](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=color%20scheme&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) and see how it's done. It's actually not that complicated to understand how the syntax works.

Good luck and make sure to share your colorscheme with the community when it's ready.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Vim's awesome documentation are a bit hard to find, but helpful once it's found.

Comment: Good suggestion to check the existing schemes.

Comment: @Beakr, you can do `:helpgrep yourterm` when the usual `:help yourterm` leads you to the wrong place too many times.

Comment: You can also push Ctrl-D to get a listing right on the spot; e.g., do ``:help yourterm``Ctrl-D. You can also just keep mashing the tab button to cycle through the available documentation for ``yourterm``.

Comment: Yes, or simply `:help yourterm<Tab>` if you have the wildmenu set. Except that `:help` uses tags whereas `:helpgrep yourterm` works with regex, just like `:Grep`. One searches in the index, the other searches in the content.

Comment: Don't forget the pretty-cool colortest.vim:  `:runtime syntax/colortest.vim`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you'll find useful this colorscheme: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=106 .

Here is the description given by author:

> The philosophy here is to provide a ready-to-uncomment list of highlight commands for all the important groups.  Then you can deviate from the default until you come up with one you like.